# Erlang, deep_reverse(Lst) function

Tags: erlang

I am doing an exercise about Erlang and I cannot implement this function.

deep_reverse(Lst)

Reverses the elements of L at all levels.

For example, if Lst is [a, [b, c, [d]], e], deep-reverse should return [e, [[d], c, b], a].

Can anyone help me with this exercise?

```
element_reverse(List) ->
     Flat = lists:flatten(List),
     lists:reverse(Flat).
```

Comment: what help you need?

Comment: What you have tried till now ?

Comment: I am following the idea. First, I extract all elements in list by using flatten function. Then, I use function reverse to create a reversed list. My current difficulty is I cannot replace elements in reversed list with elements in input list.

Comment: @TuanNguyenHoang this might not be the best way to go forward, by invoking `flatten`, you destroy the structural information in the list. A better way would be to use a recursive function with an accumulator to implement the reversal by yourself -- and not using `lists:reverse`. I am pretty sure, that the intent of the exercise is precisely this. Nevertheless, I encourage you to edit your question and show the code you have worked out already -- this makes answering simpler, and you don't get so many downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets look how a simple reverse function could look like, without the *deep* feature.

A function with 1 parameter is not sufficient, we need an accumulator, a value that is beeing carried over to the next recursive step. The accumulator is an empty list at first and on every step of the recursion, it will be filled successively.

```
simple_reverse(List) -> simple_reverse(List, []).
```

So, now we need to define a 2-parameter function so that `simple_reverse(List, [])` can be called.

```
simple_reverse([H|T], Accu) ->
  simple_reverse(T, [H] ++ Accu);

simple_reverse([], Accu) -> Accu.
```

The first part of the function definition handles lists with content. `[H|T]` means, we have a list and `H`(Head) is the first element of it, while `T`(Tail) is the rest of the list. We call `simple_reverse` again with the tail as first parameter, and accumulate the head value with the accumulator head first.

The second part deals with the case when the list is empty. When that happens we can return the accumulator (all values that have been accumulated head first).

When you understand what happens here, the implementation of a `deep_reverse` is relatively straight forward. If you don't understand what happens here, you should read a bit about [lists](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists) and [recursion](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion).

```
deep_reverse(List) -> deep_reverse(List, []).

deep_reverse([H|T], Accu) ->
  case H of
    [_|_] -> deep_reverse(T, [deep_reverse(H)] ++ Accu);
    _     -> deep_reverse(T, [H] ++ Accu)
  end;

deep_reverse([], Accu) -> Accu.
```

Here we take a look at the `H`-value. `H` can either be a list itself (`[_|_]`) or something else (`_`). The recursion is essentially the same as `simple_reverse`, except when `H` is a list. If it is a list, we have to call `deep_reverse` again on `H` when the recursion is beeing executed.

Here are some links if you struggle to understand the syntax: [case-expressions](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#in-case-of) and [pattern-matching](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. However, when I try running the function with List=[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, 7], 8], 9], the result seems not correct. It should return [9, 8, [7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2], 1] instead of [9,[8,[7,6,5],4,3],2,1]

Comment: Are you sure about that? It doesn't seem right. In your solution '2' is part of the first inner list, wich can never be the case, since in the example it is part of the outermost list. The same goes for '8', wich is part of the outer list, when it should be part of the first inner list.

Comment: Oops, it is my fault. You are right. Sorry about that! But can you show me the way to modify above function so that it can return [9, 8, [7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2], 1] ?

Comment: erm... nope, don't really have time for that. You should figure that one out for yourself.